# In express router method is not working if i serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my node application first i want to serve my static files and then using router method depending upon the incoming request i will query the DB and get the body of the html page then i will send this body content to the client side and finally using Backbone.js i will render this body in my html page.Now what is my problem means express router method is not working if i serve static files.But if i remove the below line means my router is working.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

app.js

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){

   console.log('router called successfully...');
   res.send('body of the page');
   res.end();

});

app.listen(8011);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Your unnecessary anonymous function is screwing up how the middleware is supposed to work. The above line is in 95% or more of all express sample apps. Not sure why you decided to deviate from that, but your version is a useless middleware that creates a static middleware and immediately discards it.

Comment: yes app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); this will work but my router function is wont work if i use this means.

Comment: Do you have an "index.html" file in your `public` directory? When you say "not working", please develop the habit of describing what it `IS` doing or what error you are getting vs just "not working" which is not that helpful to folks looking to assist you.

Comment: Yes i have index.html page in the public folder.Then in router method i have added one console.log message that message is not displaying so thats y i'm telling its not working.

Comment: This code works, copy & paste the code in a file and run in another instance of shell : `curl 127.0.0.1:8011` and `curl 127.0.0.1:8011/index.html` ( if `index.html` is the name of the file in your `/public` folder! )

Comment: @drinchev index.html page is displaying without any problem.But router method is not working..

Comment: Well I've pasted this code to a file and all seems to work. You should know that your router will be activated only on `/` path, e.g. `/anything` will not activate your router!

Comment: @drinchev In my browser if i enter http://localhost:8011/ this url means that router method should display the console message but its not displaying..if i remove this 'app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));' code means my router displaying the console message.

Comment: The message isn't displayed in your browser it's displayed on your console, since node is a server and not a JavaScript extension.

Comment: @drinchev yes i know i'm expecting the result in console not in browser in my case i'm expecting result in terminal because i'm using ubuntu also running my app.js file in terminal.

Comment: @sachin requesting `/` is being handled by the static middleware (which will return `index.html` in the public root if it exists – which is does, according to your comments), and because that is declared earlier, your route handler will never be called.

Comment: @sachin move `app.use(express.static())` to after your `app.get()` route (but you say you want to serve static files first, so that might not be possible for your setup), or remove/rename `index.html` in your public directory.

Comment: @robertklep thank you for ur valuable info i will reome that index.html from public folder..